# How to play sound onto microphone?

Tags: audio, processing

I want to make a soundboard in the Processing language that plays sounds so the computer handles the sounds as if they were inputs from my microphone. This is my only problem about doing a soundboard. How do I make the sounds play as if they were recorded by the microphone?

I have spent an hour searching and trying to get help, but I have nothing to work with.

Comment: I don't understand the problem... do you want it to play through the speakers instead?

Comment: Sry.
No, I want it to be handled as if it was recorded through the microphone, so for example if I record my microphone, the added sound will be Heard there. 
Thanks!

Comment: And searching has come up blank so far?

Comment: Yes it really has...
I understand that the microphone is accepting to be edited atleast, but I have no idea how to access it from the Processing language.
I tried to use Minim (http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) but could not find any function or similar to help me. :(

Comment: Do you have any ideas? :(

Comment: Afraid not, I have absolutely zero experience of the 'Processing' language or audio stuff. But more information might help someone else answer it.

Answer (score 1):

> Minim provides the class AudioInput for monitoring the user’s current record source (this is often set in the sound card control panel), such as the microphone or the line-in

from

http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/quickstart/

**EDIT:**

Have you seen this?

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;

// for recording
AudioInput in;
AudioRecorder recorder;

// for playing back
AudioOutput out;
FilePlayer player;

void setup()
{
  size(512, 200, P3D);

  minim = new Minim(this);

  // get a stereo line-in: sample buffer length of 2048
  // default sample rate is 44100, default bit depth is 16
  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 2048);

  // create an AudioRecorder that will record from in to the filename specified.
  // the file will be located in the sketch's main folder.
  recorder = minim.createRecorder(in, "myrecording.wav");

  // get an output we can playback the recording on
  out = minim.getLineOut( Minim.STEREO );

  textFont(createFont("Arial", 12));
}

void draw()
{
  background(0); 
  stroke(255);
  // draw the waveforms
  // the values returned by left.get() and right.get() will be between -1 and 1,
  // so we need to scale them up to see the waveform
  for(int i = 0; i < in.left.size()-1; i++)
  {
    line(i, 50 + in.left.get(i)*50, i+1, 50 + in.left.get(i+1)*50);
    line(i, 150 + in.right.get(i)*50, i+1, 150 + in.right.get(i+1)*50);
  }

  if ( recorder.isRecording() )
  {
    text("Now recording...", 5, 15);
  }
  else
  {
    text("Not recording.", 5, 15);
  }
}

void keyReleased()
{
  if ( key == 'r' ) 
  {
    // to indicate that you want to start or stop capturing audio data, 
    // you must callstartRecording() and stopRecording() on the AudioRecorder object. 
    // You can start and stop as many times as you like, the audio data will 
    // be appended to the end of to the end of the file. 
    if ( recorder.isRecording() ) 
    {
      recorder.endRecord();
    }
    else 
    {
      recorder.beginRecord();
    }
  }
  if ( key == 's' )
  {
    // we've filled the file out buffer, 
    // now write it to a file of the type we specified in setup
    // in the case of buffered recording, 
    // this will appear to freeze the sketch for sometime, if the buffer is large
    // in the case of streamed recording, 
    // it will not freeze as the data is already in the file and all that is being done
    // is closing the file.
    // save returns the recorded audio in an AudioRecordingStream, 
    // which we can then play with a FilePlayer
    if ( player != null )
    {
        player.unpatch( out );
        player.close();
    }
    player = new FilePlayer( recorder.save() );
    player.patch( out );
    player.play();
  }
}
```

It's from here:

http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audiorecorder_class_audiorecorder.html

Comment: Yes, but "monitoring" isn't enough it seems. It can't do what I want as I see.

Comment: @EliasL It can record and playback recorded audio as well. See the edit in the answer. :)